# Powershell On Mailbox Creation (Office 365)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Is there an approach that allows "events" in Exchange Online so that a piece of code can be called when a condition is met, such as whenever a new mailbox is created?

For example, if I wanted to include a couple extra folders with a specific retention policy whenever a new mailbox is created.

No known examples on technet.

Comment: you can run a scheduled script that check the `whenCreated` hourly/daily, or you can use mailbox auditing and act when new mailbox created...

Comment: Ty for the advice